# What is the precise meaning of the word "avicha"?

Tags: hebrew, translation

I search the meaning of the word "Avicha" (not sure how it is written in hebrew. I have seen it used in the terms "Mussar Avicha", "Birchos Avicha", "elohai avicha" etc. but I can never find the translation of just the word itself "Avicha".

Answer (score 3):

Your (*masculine singular*) father

Answer (score 1):

In some contexts, it could mean "your family" or even "your heritage."